# How to set up caching and compression correctly in Joomla

Tags: caching, joomla, compression, pagespeed, http-accept-encoding

I'm developing Joomla websites and I've just been running some page speed tests at http://tools.pingdom.com/. It gives me a zero score for browser caching. I have caching already enabled in Joomla global configuration. Is there something else I should be doing for caching to work properly?

I also have GZIP enabled through Joomla global config, but the tool says I need to `Specify a Vary: Accept-Encoding header` so my resource compression score is pretty low too. Is this something else that I should be doing, or should the server be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable browser caching you have to enable [cache plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Cache).

> **Page Caching**
>
> ```
> Configuration: Built-in Plugin (Extensions -> Plugin Manager -> System - Cache)
> Caches: each whole page of your site
> Based on: URL
> More info:
>     Optional browser caching: Also caches on your visitors' browser/computer
>     Only caches pages for guest visitors (not for logged in visitors)
> ```

You will have improvement in the site speed but it is not recommended for sites that content updates often or e-commerce projects.

You could also check [joomla extensions directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/cache) for a 3rd party cache solution.

Hope this helps